# Xcode: How to find out what NSLog automatically casts into?

Tags: xcode, casting, save, loading, nslog

Hello I am trying to save and load my game data. It cannot read an integer properly from a file, however it can read a string properly though...

Strangely enough when I print the number with NSLog it works!. However if I try to use the value or pass it into another value it doesn't.

Now I could 'fix' this by converting all the numbers into strings and then saving it, then loading the strings and converting it back to numbers. However I would like to know the proper way of doing it. Also there are 1600 tiles not including other data so that would be a noticeable overhead.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong or what NSLog is doing automatically?

Below is the code section relevant to the question. mapData[i][j] is an array of integers representing whats on a tile.

```
-(void)saveGame
{
NSLog(@"%s", "Saved");
NSString *temp = [self saveFilePath];
NSLog(@"%s %@", "FilePath", temp);

NSMutableArray *values = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1602];
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int a = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 40; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < 40; j++)
    {
        //values[i] = mapData[j][k];
        [values addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:mapData[i][j]]];
        NSLog(@"%d, %d", i, j);
        NSLog(@"%s, %d", "Map Data: ", mapData[i][j]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [values objectAtIndex:a]);
        a++;
    }
}

// test letter OK
NSString * letterA = @"a";
[values addObject:[NSString stringWithString:letterA]];

// test independant number
NSInteger aNum = 888;
[values addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:aNum]];

NSArray *value = [NSArray arrayWithArray:values];
// test conversion OK
a = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 40; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < 40; j++)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", [value objectAtIndex:a]);
        a++;
    }
}
 NSLog(@"%@", [value objectAtIndex:a]); // letter OK
a++;
NSLog(@"%@", [value objectAtIndex:a]); // number OK
[value writeToFile:[self saveFilePath] atomically:YES]; // atomically means all or    nothing. i.e power fail will not save half

}

-(NSString *)saveFilePath
{
    NSArray * path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask, YES);

return [[path objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savefile.plist"];
}

-(void)loadGame
{
NSLog(@"%s", "Loaded");
NSString *loadPath = [self saveFilePath];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:loadPath];
if(fileExists)
{
    NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:loadPath];
    int a = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 40; j++)
        {
            //mapData[i][j] = [values objectAtIndex:a];
            //mapData[i][j] = (NSInteger)[values objectAtIndex:a];

            NSInteger * tempNumber = [values objectAtIndex:a];
            NSLog(@"%@", tempNumber); // YES!
            int tempInt = (int)tempNumber; 
            NSLog(@"%d", tempInt); // no
            mapData[i][j] = tempNumber; 

            NSLog(@"%d, %d, %d", a , i, j);
            NSLog(@"%s, %d", "Loaded Map Data: ", mapData[i][j]); // no
            a++;
        }
    }
    // string works but integer doesnt...
    NSString * letter;
    letter = [values objectAtIndex:a];
    NSLog(@"%@", letter); // YES

    // this number OK - needs pointer AND NSLog...
    a++;
    NSInteger * number;
    number = [values objectAtIndex:a];
    NSLog(@"%@", number); // YES
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nvm I figured it out. NSLog was automatically unwrapping the numbers for me. Manually unwrapping will display the correct numbers instead of memory addresses.